# gsuite log in vs Google + login

Tags: single-sign-on, google-oauth, google-workspace, google-oauth-java-client

I am trying to provide google sign in for my users. I am confused here between the Gsuite log in and the google plus log in. I tried to google it and know the difference but cant find any related blog which explains the difference between google+ login and gsuite login. All i can find is Gsuite is a cloud based services where we get access to gmail,hangouts,Calender, Drive etc.,. I am trying to implement OAUTh2 for Gsuite users. Can any one has a reference or an explanation here is greatly appreciated.

Also who exactly is a Gsuite user? Is it someone from my organisation or from the end user perspective?

Answer (score 0):

Google provides a unique identity across Google services (myaccount.google.com)
this identity is used for gsuite, gmail, g+ etc
a Gsuite user is a user identity that has a subscription to the gsuite services for a company (or EDU or ORG - licencing)
nevertheless, any Google account can use a gsuite service (available to public gmail users also). Non Google Accounts can access data on Gsuite when specific sharing parameters are in place.